# canvas - Tiles not rendering completely

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a tile based game in Javascript, using the Canvas API. I have been following the [square tilemap scrolling tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Tilemaps/Square_tilemaps_implementation%3A_Scrolling_maps) at MDN. It works, but when you move the camera, it doesn't render all the tiles, especially when you move it down and to the right. I have tried copying and pasting and replacing my code with the tutorial's but it still doesn't work.

Here is the client code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var tiles = new Image();
tiles.src = "img/tiles.png";
var socket = io();

function Loader(game) {
  this.game = game;
  this.images = {}
}

Loader.prototype.loadImage = function(id, url, tile) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = url;
  this.images[id] = {
    img: image,
    url: url,
    tile: tile
  }
}

Loader.prototype.ready = function() {
  this.game.loadImages(this.images);
}



function Game(canvas, map,camera) {
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.monsters = [];
  this.player = {};
  this.map = map;
  this.timestamp = function() {
    return window.performance && window.performance.now ? window.performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
  }
  this.camera = camera||{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 256,
    height: 256
  }

}

Game.prototype.init = function(ts) {
  this.current = {
    tileset: this.images[ts]
  }
  this.width = this.map.cols * this.map.tsize;
  this.height = this.map.rows * this.map.tsize;
  this.canvas.height=1000;
  this.canvas.width=1000;
  this.camera.maxX = this.map.cols * this.map.tsize - this.camera.width;
  this.camera.maxY = this.map.rows * this.map.tsize - this.camera.height;
}

Game.prototype.loadImages = function(images) {
  this.images = images;
}

Game.prototype.start = function() {

  this.now = 0;
  this.dt = 0;
  this.last = this.timestamp();
  this.frame();
}

Game.prototype.update = function(delta) {
  var dirx = 0;
    var diry = 0;
    if (KEYS.LEFT) { dirx = -1; }
    if (KEYS.RIGHT) { dirx = 1; }
    if (KEYS.UP) { diry = -1; }
    if (KEYS.DOWN) { diry = 1; }

    this.camera.move(delta, dirx, diry);
}

Game.prototype.render = function(delta) {
  this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
  var startCol = Math.floor(this.camera.x / this.map.tsize);
  var endCol = startCol + (this.camera.width / this.map.tsize);
  var startRow = Math.floor(this.camera.y / this.map.tsize);
  var endRow = startRow + (this.camera.height / this.map.tsize);
  var offsetX = -this.camera.x + startCol * this.map.tsize;
  var offsetY = -this.camera.y + startRow * this.map.tsize;
  for(var c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
    for(var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
      var tile = this.getTile(c, r);
      var x = (c - startCol) * this.map.tsize + offsetX;
      var y = (r - startRow) * this.map.tsize + offsetY;
      if(tile !== 0) {
        ctx.drawImage(
          this.current.tileset.img, //image
          (tile - 1) * this.map.tsize,
          0,
          this.map.tsize,
          this.map.tsize,
          Math.round(x),
          Math.round(y),
          this.map.tsize,
          this.map.tsize
        )
      }
    }
  }
}

Game.prototype.frame = function() {
  this.now = this.timestamp();
  this.dt = (this.now - this.last) / 1000; // duration in seconds
  this.update(this.dt);
  this.render(this.dt);
  this.last = this.now;
  requestAnimationFrame(this.frame.bind(this));
};


Game.prototype.getTile = function(x, y) {
  return this.map.layer[y * this.map.cols + x];
}


function Camera(map, width, height) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.maxX = map.cols * map.tsize - width;
    this.maxY = map.rows * map.tsize - height;
}

Camera.SPEED = 256; // pixels per second

Camera.prototype.move = function (delta, dirx, diry) {
    // move camera
    this.x += dirx * Camera.SPEED * delta;
    this.y += diry * Camera.SPEED * delta;
    // clamp values
    this.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.x, this.maxX));
    this.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.y, this.maxY));
};

var KEYS = {

};

function handleKey(down, e, key) {
  switch(key) {
    case 37:
      KEYS.LEFT = down;
      break;
    case 38:
      KEYS.UP = down;
      break;
    case 39:
      KEYS.RIGHT = down;
      break;
    case 40:
      KEYS.DOWN = down;
      break;
    default:
      KEYS[String.fromCharCode(key)] = down;
      break;
  }
};


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  handleKey(true, e, e.which);
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  handleKey(false, e, e.which);
};

function getHelp(s) {
  socket.emit('help', s);
}

var map = {
  cols: 12,
  rows: 12,
  tsize: 64,
  layer: [
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
  ]
};
var camera = new Camera(map,256,256);
var game = new Game(canvas, map,camera);

var loader = new Loader(game);

loader.loadImage('set1', 'img/tiles.png', 64);
loader.ready();

game.init('set1');
game.start();
```

You can also find the repository [here](https://github.com/spacegeek224/theescapists-mmo).

Comment: Hey spacegeek224, I edited your answer - turned your code into an executable snippet. Do you want to approve that edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game is working fine. You have a camera window of 256x256 pixel. During rendering, this space is completely filled with tiles. If you are bothered by the 'disappearing' tiles outside that camera window, either use a [clipping rectangle](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp) or reduce the canvas size to correspond to the camera size.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Loader(game) {
  this.game = game;
  this.images = {}
}

Loader.prototype.loadImage = function(id, url, tile) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = url;
  this.images[id] = {
    img: image,
    url: url,
    tile: tile
  }
}

Loader.prototype.ready = function() {
  this.game.loadImages(this.images);
}

function Game(canvas, map,camera) {
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.monsters = [];
  this.player = {};
  this.map = map;
  this.timestamp = function() {
    return window.performance && window.performance.now ? window.performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
  }
  this.camera = camera||{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 256,
    height: 256
  }

}

Game.prototype.init = function(ts) {
  this.current = {
    tileset: this.images[ts]
  }
  this.width = this.map.cols * this.map.tsize;
  this.height = this.map.rows * this.map.tsize;
  this.canvas.width = this.camera.width;
  this.canvas.height = this.camera.height;
  this.camera.maxX = this.map.cols * this.map.tsize - this.camera.width;
  this.camera.maxY = this.map.rows * this.map.tsize - this.camera.height;
}

Game.prototype.loadImages = function(images) {
  this.images = images;
}

Game.prototype.start = function() {

  this.now = 0;
  this.dt = 0;
  this.last = this.timestamp();
  this.frame();
}

Game.prototype.update = function(delta) {
  var dirx = 0;
    var diry = 0;
    if (KEYS.LEFT) { dirx = -1; }
    if (KEYS.RIGHT) { dirx = 1; }
    if (KEYS.UP) { diry = -1; }
    if (KEYS.DOWN) { diry = 1; }

    this.camera.move(delta, dirx, diry);
}

Game.prototype.render = function(delta) {
  this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
  var startCol = Math.floor(this.camera.x / this.map.tsize);
  var endCol = startCol + (this.camera.width / this.map.tsize);
  var startRow = Math.floor(this.camera.y / this.map.tsize);
  var endRow = startRow + (this.camera.height / this.map.tsize);
  var offsetX = -this.camera.x + startCol * this.map.tsize;
  var offsetY = -this.camera.y + startRow * this.map.tsize;
  for(var c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
    for(var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
      var tile = this.getTile(c, r);
      var x = (c - startCol) * this.map.tsize + offsetX;
      var y = (r - startRow) * this.map.tsize + offsetY;
      if(tile !== 0) {
        ctx.drawImage(
          this.current.tileset.img, //image
          (tile - 1) * this.map.tsize,
          0,
          this.map.tsize,
          this.map.tsize,
          Math.round(x),
          Math.round(y),
          this.map.tsize,
          this.map.tsize
        )
      }
    }
  }
}

Game.prototype.frame = function() {
  this.now = this.timestamp();
  this.dt = (this.now - this.last) / 1000; // duration in seconds
  this.update(this.dt);
  this.render(this.dt);
  this.last = this.now;
  requestAnimationFrame(this.frame.bind(this));
};


Game.prototype.getTile = function(x, y) {
  return this.map.layer[y * this.map.cols + x];
}


function Camera(map, width, height) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.maxX = map.cols * map.tsize - width;
    this.maxY = map.rows * map.tsize - height;
}

Camera.SPEED = 256; // pixels per second

Camera.prototype.move = function (delta, dirx, diry) {
    // move camera
    this.x += dirx * Camera.SPEED * delta;
    this.y += diry * Camera.SPEED * delta;
    // clamp values
    this.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.x, this.maxX));
    this.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.y, this.maxY));
};

var KEYS = {

};

function handleKey(down, e, key) {
  switch(key) {
    case 37:
      KEYS.LEFT = down;
      break;
    case 38:
      KEYS.UP = down;
      break;
    case 39:
      KEYS.RIGHT = down;
      break;
    case 40:
      KEYS.DOWN = down;
      break;
    default:
      KEYS[String.fromCharCode(key)] = down;
      break;
  }
};


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  handleKey(true, e, e.which);
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  handleKey(false, e, e.which);
};

function getHelp(s) {
  socket.emit('help', s);
}

var map = {
  cols: 12,
  rows: 12,
  tsize: 64,
  layer: [
        3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
  ]
};
var camera = new Camera(map,256,256);
var game = new Game(canvas, map,camera);

var loader = new Loader(game);

loader.loadImage('set1', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPVJH.jpg', 64);
loader.ready();

game.init('set1');
game.start();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If you want to have a fixed canvas size and e. g. center the camera window in the middle, use this approach:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Loader(game) {
  this.game = game;
  this.images = {}
}

Loader.prototype.loadImage = function(id, url, tile) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = url;
  this.images[id] = {
    img: image,
    url: url,
    tile: tile
  }
}

Loader.prototype.ready = function() {
  this.game.loadImages(this.images);
}

function Game(canvas, map,camera) {
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.monsters = [];
  this.player = {};
  this.map = map;
  this.timestamp = function() {
    return window.performance && window.performance.now ? window.performance.now() : new Date().getTime();
  }
  this.camera = camera||{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 256,
    height: 256
  }

}

Game.prototype.init = function(ts) {
  this.current = {
    tileset: this.images[ts]
  }
  this.width = this.map.cols * this.map.tsize;
  this.height = this.map.rows * this.map.tsize;
  this.camera.maxX = this.map.cols * this.map.tsize - this.camera.width;
  this.camera.maxY = this.map.rows * this.map.tsize - this.camera.height;
}

Game.prototype.loadImages = function(images) {
  this.images = images;
}

Game.prototype.start = function() {

  this.now = 0;
  this.dt = 0;
  this.last = this.timestamp();
  this.frame();
}

Game.prototype.update = function(delta) {
  var dirx = 0;
    var diry = 0;
    if (KEYS.LEFT) { dirx = -1; }
    if (KEYS.RIGHT) { dirx = 1; }
    if (KEYS.UP) { diry = -1; }
    if (KEYS.DOWN) { diry = 1; }

    this.camera.move(delta, dirx, diry);
}

Game.prototype.render = function(delta) {
  this.ctx.fillRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
  this.ctx.save();
  this.ctx.translate((this.canvas.width-this.camera.width)/2, (this.canvas.height-this.camera.height)/2);
  this.ctx.rect(0,0,this.camera.width, this.camera.height);
  this.ctx.clip();
  var startCol = Math.floor(this.camera.x / this.map.tsize);
  var endCol = startCol + (this.camera.width / this.map.tsize);
  var startRow = Math.floor(this.camera.y / this.map.tsize);
  var endRow = startRow + (this.camera.height / this.map.tsize);
  var offsetX = -this.camera.x + startCol * this.map.tsize;
  var offsetY = -this.camera.y + startRow * this.map.tsize;
  for(var c = startCol; c <= endCol; c++) {
    for(var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
      var tile = this.getTile(c, r);
      var x = (c - startCol) * this.map.tsize + offsetX;
      var y = (r - startRow) * this.map.tsize + offsetY;
      if(tile !== 0) {
        ctx.drawImage(
          this.current.tileset.img, //image
          (tile - 1) * this.map.tsize,
          0,
          this.map.tsize,
          this.map.tsize,
          Math.round(x),
          Math.round(y),
          this.map.tsize,
          this.map.tsize
        )
      }
    }
  }
  this.ctx.restore();
}

Game.prototype.frame = function() {
  this.now = this.timestamp();
  this.dt = (this.now - this.last) / 1000; // duration in seconds
  this.update(this.dt);
  this.render(this.dt);
  this.last = this.now;
  requestAnimationFrame(this.frame.bind(this));
};


Game.prototype.getTile = function(x, y) {
  return this.map.layer[y * this.map.cols + x];
}


function Camera(map, width, height) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.maxX = map.cols * map.tsize - width;
    this.maxY = map.rows * map.tsize - height;
}

Camera.SPEED = 256; // pixels per second

Camera.prototype.move = function (delta, dirx, diry) {
    // move camera
    this.x += dirx * Camera.SPEED * delta;
    this.y += diry * Camera.SPEED * delta;
    // clamp values
    this.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.x, this.maxX));
    this.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.y, this.maxY));
};

var KEYS = {

};

function handleKey(down, e, key) {
  switch(key) {
    case 37:
      KEYS.LEFT = down;
      break;
    case 38:
      KEYS.UP = down;
      break;
    case 39:
      KEYS.RIGHT = down;
      break;
    case 40:
      KEYS.DOWN = down;
      break;
    default:
      KEYS[String.fromCharCode(key)] = down;
      break;
  }
};


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  handleKey(true, e, e.which);
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  handleKey(false, e, e.which);
};

function getHelp(s) {
  socket.emit('help', s);
}

var map = {
  cols: 12,
  rows: 12,
  tsize: 64,
  layer: [
        3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
        3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
  ]
};
var camera = new Camera(map,256,256);
var game = new Game(canvas, map,camera);

var loader = new Loader(game);

loader.loadImage('set1', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPVJH.jpg', 64);
loader.ready();

game.init('set1');
game.start();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: That fixed one half of the problem, but it still doesn't load the tiles on the bottom or the right until the white space is equal to the size of the tile.

Comment: I just tried it and all it does is change the camera size from 5 to 4

Comment: Your camera size is set to 254 pixel which corresponds to 4 tiles à 64 pixel. What do you want to render outside your camera window?

Comment: I revised my answer, the canvas size now corresponds to your camera size.

Comment: Now it works, thanks! I have a question, is there a way to do it without the camera size and canvas size being the same, and without using clipping rectangles? It seems like there should be a way to do it.

Comment: You can of course scale the content visible in your camera window to fill the whole canvas. But I don't recommend that, I prefer keeping the canvas at a fixed size and scaling it later via CSS to fit your screen. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The size of the camera isn't what it should be when I change the values, and when I change the values, even if the camera and canvas have the same dimensions, it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you please revise your question and clarify what you want to achieve? I don't know what you want the size of the camera to be, and what you mean with "change the values".

Comment: I want the camera to smoothly render the tiles, and be intact, no matter the size of the canvas. I also want to be able to change the size of the camera.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113529/discussion-between-le-m-and-spacegeek224).